# Spring REST - cannot force H2 database to create keys manually

Tags: java, spring, rest, h2

I've tried to learn basics of Spring using [Spring Rest Tutorial](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-rest) but one thing is really interesting to me.

Entity class:

```
@Entity
class Employee {

    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
    private String name;
    private String role;

    Employee() {}

    Employee(String name, String role) {

        this.name = name;
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return this.role;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Employee))
            return false;
        Employee employee = (Employee) o;
        return Objects.equals(this.id, employee.id) && Objects.equals(this.name, employee.name)
                && Objects.equals(this.role, employee.role);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(this.id, this.name, this.role);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" + "id=" + this.id + ", name='" + this.name + '\'' + ", role='" + this.role + '\'' + '}';
    }
}
```

I think that `replaceEmployee` method in EmployeeController is bugged - there is a piece of code:

```
  @PutMapping("/employees/{id}")
  Employee replaceEmployee(@RequestBody Employee newEmployee, @PathVariable Long id) {
    
    return repository.findById(id)
      .map(employee -> {
        employee.setName(newEmployee.getName());
        employee.setRole(newEmployee.getRole());
        return repository.save(employee);
      })
      .orElseGet(() -> {
        newEmployee.setId(id);
        return repository.save(newEmployee);
      });
  }
```

Snippet suggests that in case there is no `Employee` with `id`, a new Employee is created with `id` from request path. I've tested it and it appears that Employee is indeed created but with auto-incremented `id`.

Modified code:

```
@PutMapping("/employees/{id}")
Employee replaceEmployee(@RequestBody Employee newEmployee, @PathVariable Long id) {

return repository.findById(id)
    .map(employee -> {
        employee.setName(newEmployee.getName());
        employee.setRole(newEmployee.getRole());

        Employee result = repository.save(employee);

        logger.info("PUT: Trying to replace + " + employee);
        logger.info("PUT: replaced " + employee + " with " + result);

        return result;
    })
    .orElseGet(() -> {
        newEmployee.setId(id);
        Employee result = repository.save(newEmployee);

        logger.info("PUT: Trying to add" + newEmployee);
        logger.info("PUT: add " + result);

        return result;
    });
}
```

Curl command:

```
curl -X PUT localhost:8080/employees/234 -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{"name": "Samwise Gamgee", "role": "gardener"}'
```

with result:

```
{"id":3,"name":"Samwise Gamgee","role":"gardener"}
```

Logs:

```
2021-08-17 15:53:34.956  INFO 34321 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] payroll.EmployeeController               : PUT: Trying to addEmployee{id=234, name='Samwise Gamgee', role='gardener'}
2021-08-17 15:53:34.956  INFO 34321 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] payroll.EmployeeController               : PUT: add Employee{id=3, name='Samwise Gamgee', role='gardener'}
```

My question is: Is there any possibility to enable manual `id` field creation in `Employee` entity? And if so, how to enable it?

Edit:
To be precise, I'd like to make generation strategy as follows:

1. If no `id` is specified in new `Employee`, database should generate it using some kind of auto-generation strategy - it should happen also in any possible fault cases, e.g. app is trying to save object with `id` already occuring in db.
2. If not, take `id` from new object.

Answer (score 0):

Annotation `@GeneratedValue` on property `id` of `Employee`  is setting the id of the entity. You could remove it and try out.